# How to track changes in the currently focused input in Vue.js?

Tags: vue.js, focus, computed-properties

With `document.activeElement` I can get a reference to the currently focused element, but of course this isn't reactive so I can't use it in computed properties.

What is the best way to solve this? I would like any component in my Vue app to be able to listen for changes in the `value`, `selectionStart` and `selectionEnd` properties of the currently focused input on the page.

How could I achieve something like this? Or is there an alternative (better) way to track properties of the currently focused input in Vue?

Answer (score 0):

You can add eventListener within `created` with`focusin` event

```
created() {
  document.addEventListener('focusin', this.doSomething)
},
```

And recieve this focused element in `doSomething` with param `e` within methods

```
methods: {
  doSomething (e) {
    console.log(e.target)
  }
```

Comment: How does this help me track changes in the `value`, `selectionStart` and `selectionEnd` properties of the focused input? Sure, it'll let me see their values at the time of focus, but what if they change at any point **while** the input is focused?

Comment: Did you mean that you want to get the highlighted text inside input?

Comment: Yes, or the text that isn't highlighted... That's what `selectionStart` and `selectionEnd` tells you. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement#Properties